# SAP Simple Transformation with arbitrary XML tags

Tags: xml, xml-deserialization, abap-st

I have XML of unknown structure and I want to apply ST (Simple Transformation) on it to get "somehow" that content out of XML into ABAP structures.

For now I have following test report:

```
report  ztbu_st_with_copy.

data: lf_xml type string.
concatenate '<tab><obj>'
              '<id>A1</id>'
              '<first>Erste</first>'
              '<second>Zweite</second>'
            '</obj><obj>'
              '<id>B2</id>'
              '<item>'
                '<here>Tady</here>'
                '<there>Tam</there>'
              '</item>'
            '</obj>'
            '</tab>'
       into lf_xml.

types: begin of ys_obj,
         id type string,
         rest type string,
       end of ys_obj,
       yt_obj type standard table of ys_obj.

data: lt_obj type yt_obj.

call transformation ztbu_st_copy_test
  source xml lf_xml
  result root = lt_obj.

uline.

data: ls_obj like line of lt_obj.
loop at lt_obj into ls_obj.
  write: / sy-tabix, ls_obj-id.
endloop.

uline.
```

and I have following ST transformation ZTBU_ST_COPY_TEST (the one called above):

```
<?sap.transform simple?>
<tt:transform xmlns:tt="http://www.sap.com/transformation-templates">

<tt:root name="ROOT"/>

<tt:template>
  <tab>
  <tt:loop ref=".ROOT" name="obj">
      <obj>
        <id>
          <tt:value ref="$obj.ID" />
        </id>
        <tt:skip />
      </obj>
  </tt:loop>
  </tab>
</tt:template>

</tt:transform>
```

Now it works fine and it will bring IDs into the fields of table LT_OBJ. However the rest is ignored due to use of `<TT:SKIP>`. My goal would be to get the rest of XML document (these FIRST, SECOND, HERE and THERE or any arbitrary XML) into field REST in "some" format - probably as rough XML stored in STRING variable.

I understand I need to replace `<TT:SKIP>` with something smarter, but I can't figure it out what that should be... Any idea?

*Side note: yes, I know, it would be better to use XSLT or something else, instead of ST, but I have no choice and I need to make it using ST.*

Comment: I wouldn't call it "unknown XML."  You seem to be assuming that the XML starts with <tab> and has a number of <obj> in it, each with one <id> and other unknown elements.  Is this safe to assume?

Comment: Yes, this is safe to assume, <tab>, <obj> and <id> are known, but I'm after the rest of the things, and they are truly unknown...

Answer (score 1):

ST are constraint since the can be used both ways (abap <-> xml). They are great because they are fast. But they map ABAP values to XML nodes and there's not much options there. I beleive you can't do this with ST. SXML would be best for your senario.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to get raw XML in generated transformations for proxy services. For your example the transformation looks like this:

```
<?sap.transform simple?>
<tt:transform xmlns:tt="http://www.sap.com/transformation-templates">

  <tt:root name="ROOT"/>

 <tt:template>
    <tab>
      <tt:loop name="obj" ref=".ROOT">
        <obj tt:ap="y" tt:option="allNsps,noRootAttr" tt:value-ref="$obj.REST"/>
      </tt:loop>
    </tab>
  </tt:template>

</tt:transform>
```

Note that this doesn't parse the id. Everything within the `obj` tag is put into `REST`. Also the XML cannot be completely unknown because you have to know the surrounding tag of your fragment. (In this case `obj`)

To make it work the type of `REST`has to be of `XSDANY` (a `RAWSTRING`). In your code:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ys_obj,
         id   TYPE string,
         rest TYPE xsdany,
       END OF ys_obj,
       yt_obj TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ys_obj.
```

To transform xstrings to cstrings you can use class `cl_proxy_service`. In your write code:

```
LOOP AT lt_obj INTO ls_obj.
  WRITE: / sy-tabix, ls_obj-id, cl_proxy_service=>xstring2cstring( ls_obj-rest ).
ENDLOOP.
```

The important bit in the transformation is the `tt:option` attribute. You can look it up in the Keyword documentation.

Comment: `Note that this doesn't parse the id` yes, this parses the id, I just tried your code and see it parses all.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a SAP developer's license, this is very possible through the SDK provided with the license.
I've written something similar using VB.NET, if you're interested in some samples let me know.

Comment: See the side note: I need this to go with ST, and I have no other option. - If I could go for free style XML processing, I can well stay on ABAP side and it would be fine. But I need this to be done in ST.